# Graded version of Lazard's criterion

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

[Lazard's criterion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lazard%27s%20criterion) says that a module over a commutative ring is flat if and only if it is a filtered colimit of free modules. Does the graded version hold, i.e.: A graded module over a graded commutative ring is flat (w.r.t. the usual graded module tensor product) if is a filtered colimit of graded free modules?